# Recently treated flag in flag history

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags, flag-history

I was checking on my flag history and I noticed a new disputed one. As I'm kinda new to reviewing, I'd like to improve myself and so take a look at disputed flags I can get. That way I improve my flagging pattern.

In the flag history, all flags are listed by date (newest first) and sometimes, pending flags could be treated after quite some time. But when it is treated and declared disputed/declined, there is no way to know which one it is, unless you remember exactly the post name.

Is there a existing way to look for 'last treated flag'? If not, would you approve of such a feature?

Comment: Cross-site Meta feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119816/248731

Comment: That's an interesting thread! Although, a list of disputed flags could lead to the same issue if there is a lot of them. What about some kind of notification when your flag is disputed and maybe an comment from the user/mod who disputed it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this has been completed, in that you can now filter your flag history based on how the flag was processed - by helpful, declined, disputed, etc.

Comment: You have no idea how long I've waited for this. I'm going to celebrate by going on a rampaging flagging spree!... *I kid, I kid* ...