# Is there a way to sort/filter Flagged post?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there a way to sort/filter [Flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1213296) post by helpful, declined,   disputed? So, i can view which flagged are declined, disputed easily.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291911/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at the moment there is no way to sort/filter flags in your flag history.

There is, however, a feature request for this on Meta Stack Exchange: [Flagging summary improvement: filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92484/flagging-summary-improvement-filters)

Comment: If that feature request accepted then it become easy to filter flags.